# Could a strong solar flare blind the eyes of living things that were out in the open?

Tags: space, energy, weapon-mass-destruction, light

I would like to know on how powerful a solar flare must be to affect blind the eyes of living things, if it's indeed possible. Will it blind only half of the planet, or will it emit for a day or two? Will the temperature rise high on such level and burn combustible elements or not?

Comment: Obligatory Xkcd: https://what-if.xkcd.com/73/

Answer (score 6):

Sure.  For some definition of strong and some definition of solar flare.  Realistically, not a chance.

Most blindness due to a flash of light is temporary.  If it lasts more than a few moments, it is known as "flash blindness."  It's what flashbang grenades rely on to disorient enemies.  It is transient.  Even its nastier brother, arc eye, named after the effects received by welders with point source energy sources several times hotter than the surface of the sun, they don't last for very long.

To do the job, you really have to scar the eye.  This takes a **lot** of power.  I'm assuming you're not talking about blinding the eyes of the living whose eyelids were peeled open and forced to look at the flare for minutes on end.  The damage will have to be done fast enough to do the damage before the eye's natural responses (such as blinking) take over to protect it.

There are people who have to worry about these things.  If you are into telescopes, you are warned that you should never point a large telescope at the sun without protective layers to cut down its brightness.   Consider: from one rough estimate, it takes about 10 seconds of staring right at the sun to cause permanent damage due to retinal burning.  Blinking occurs in under a tenth of a second, so **if you look at something 100 times brighter than the sun, it'll blind you faster than you can blink.***

Now, think about how powerful a solar flare would need to be to be 100 times brighter than the sun.  It'd definitely have to get close to us to get that level of brightness.

**At some point, we're going to have to start talking technicalities: at what point does a "solar flare" transition into "the sun is going nova?**"  Right around that point is where a flare could make someone blind.

EDIT: I'd like to provide an update based on personal experience from the eclipse that just happened in 2017, roughly 2 years after the original answer.  I had the privilege of getting to watch the eclipse from the path of totality.  I also had the privilege of getting to bring my 8" telescope up for the event.  During the totality, I was able to take my filter off and gaze at the sun.  Lo and behold, on one tiny corner of the eyepiece was a beautiful pink/red solar flare, glowing with the Hydrogen spectra.  This find made me ecstatic, and I quickly gave everyone in my group a chance to see it before the totality vanished (an 8" scope gathers about 2500x more light than the human eye, and focuses it all on your retina, so the safety margin is 2500 more strict, and the clock is ticking!).

I point out this story because I was *ecstatic* about getting to see a solar flare, which vanished instantly once any part of the sun peeked out from behind the moon, awash in a far brighter light.  A solar flare that could blind people would not be a solar flare -- it would have to be so massive that one might call it the birth of a second sun.  It would have to be millions of times bigger than the flares we see today, just to be visible by the naked eye, much less blinding.

---

* *Disclaimer: This information is provided for reference and entertainment purposes only.  No one should look into the sun simply because of the back of the envelope calculations made on StackExchange without any cited resources.  Use common sense*

Comment: Thanks very logically thought out answer. Do you have any speculations on what could've make living things go blind on the massive scale within the shortest time possible. PS: I wanna start a book from a disaster that made 80% of living things go blind and the story resolves around blind society and "seekers" community.

Comment: I would stick to physical causes.  When doing research for this answer, I found that virtually all documented cases of blindness are either due to physical trauma to the eye (from objects or bacteria/viri/fungi/amoeba), or due to damage to the occipital lobe (meningitis, stroke, etc.).  So I'd say the fastest way would be a particularly brutal microorganism that figures out how to sneak past everyone's defenses.  Alternatively, there could be some really interesting games could could play if an organism infected everyone first, then simultaniously cut off their occipital lobe blood supply

Comment: Thank you, so much. You gave me guidelines on what part of research I should be focused on.

Comment: As you mentioned, can a sun go nova and then implode back? In hot multi second. Maybe nova can gouge eyes in hot split second. Theoretically ofc

Comment: Not really.  "The sun going nova" is a progressive event which can blind people... but mostly because it involves the sun expanding large enough to engulf Earth's entire orbit.  Technically people would go blind, but the, "set on fire and vaporized into atoms bit" does put a damper on the storytelling.

Comment: @UnduLationer there is a movie like that, don't know if you've watched it or not. Maybe you can get some further insights about your story there. Though I say that, I don't actually remember the name of the movie... but anyways, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Cort Ammon nailed it but he only addressed a piece of the issue.  Lets assume the star can produce light at those levels and see what happens:

1)  Only those who were unfortunate enough to be looking in the general direction of the star when it flared would have any eye damage and for most of them it would be somewhere off to the side rather than in the high precision area.  My wife has a laser burn in her eye and doesn't even notice it.  (The laser was in the hands of a retinal surgeon, this wasn't an accident.)  You're not going to get anywhere near that percentage of the population.

2)  If the light lasts few are actually going to look at it.  You aren't going to get many more victims.  Everyone exposed will be shielding their eyes against the intolerable brilliance (everywhere will be too bright), not looking at it.

3)  If the light lasts very long you're going to have major thermal issues.  People will cook, blindness will be the least of the problems.